# Windows Phone 8: Moving Event Handlers into the base View class

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a number of views in my Windows Phone 8 app that share a lot of similarity, so I created a base class to contain the common logic. In general, this approach has worked great, but with one limitation -  I am unable to move the common event handling logic into the base class. Here is the simplified version of what I am trying to achieve:

1. The base class defines a method which my sub-classes should use to handle a button click event in their respective application bars.

   `public class BaseView : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
      protected void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        MessageBox.Show("Button Pressed");
      }
    }`
2. The XAML for the inheriting view looks like this (showing only the relevant part). Note the ApplicationBarIconButton's event handler. My intention is that the OnButtonClick method, defined in the base view, is called.

   `<base:BaseView
   x:Class="EventHandlersInBaseClassBugRepro.MainPage"
   xmlns:base ="clr-namespace:EventHandlersInBaseClassBugRepro"
   xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
   .....    >`

   `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
       <shell:ApplicationBar IsMenuEnabled="False">
           <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton
               IconUri="/Assets/Tiles/FlipCycleTileSmall.png" 
               Text="Click" 
               Click="OnButtonClick"/>
       </shell:ApplicationBar>
   </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>`

The application compiles, but at runtime I am getting this exception:

```
 {System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Failed to assign to property     'Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBarIconButton.Click'. [Line: 22 Position: 23]
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at EventHandlersInBaseClassBugRepro.MainPage.InitializeComponent()
   at EventHandlersInBaseClassBugRepro.MainPage..ctor()}
```

I saw a similar question here [Silverlight: Can I set an event to a base class event handler in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363776/silverlight-can-i-set-an-event-to-a-base-class-event-handler-in-xaml). My interpretation of the answer suggests that the approach I am using should work, yet the exception.
Is what I am trying to do possible?

Comment: Try to mark the OnButtonClick method as a public one

Comment: Marking the OnButtonClick as public did not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Remember `Events` are a delegate that should only be invoked in the class that declared them.
In your scenario you havent declared an `Event` in the BaseView. 
Also mark the OnButtonClick invoke method as `Virtual` so that it can be overridden in derived classes. Try

```
public class BaseView : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public event EventHandler ButtonClicked;

    public virtual void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Base Button Click");
    }
}
```

In your derived class .cs you will need to override OnButtonClick like this

```
    public override void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // do derived class logic here
        MessageBox.Show("Derived class hit");
        // calls BaseView event invoke method
        base.OnButtonClicked(sender, e);
    }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I am already using the approach that you suggested, though I did not have to declare the EventHandler in my base class. Still, my question was around the possibility of not having to override the event handlers in the child classes since all of them simply call base.OnButtonClick.

Comment: Looking at your code you are not using the approach I suggested overriding the OnButtonClicked. Your question was moving your event handlers into the base class. I suggest you edit the question

Comment: I think my original code accurately reflects the question I asked. I believe your answer is that what I want to do is not possible, i.e. I will have to declare event handlers in the child classes even only to call base's logic. If you can confirm that, I will accept this as an answer.